# sound pool not finish playing entire file

Tags: android, handler, lag, soundpool

I have two issues I would like understand.

I am using `soundPool` for my sound effects and its working with no problem.
However, when I try to play cetain file (25 sec , about 400K) it doesn't play the whole file only 3-4 seconds from it .

Why and how can I fix it ?

and the second question is, should I play each effect from thread ? many threads are good ?

this is the current code :

```
static void play(final int soundID ){
    if(loaded){
        handler.post(new Runnable()
        {
        public void run()
        {
            soundpool.play(soundID, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
        }
        });
```

Comment: Check the return of the `play` method. From the spec: `Returns non-zero streamID if successful, zero if failed`

Comment: return 1 . and as i said it does play...for 3-4 sec

Comment: Yes, but it could have been failing after 3-4 seconds of playing. Does it return after 3-4 seconds or after 25 seconds?

Comment: didnt understand what to check , it return the streamId as the playing start...

Comment: I'd take `soundpool.play(soundID, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);` out of that `Runnable` (so it falls right under the if statement), see if that works or not.

Comment: i tryied this way after playing without thread did the same problem . no change

Comment: Try this instead of the soundpool play statement: `MediaPlayer.create(YourActivity.this, R.raw.your_sound).start();`, see if that plays the full sound.

Comment: this works , ill use it if i wont fix the problem with soundpool . i try to avoid using MediaPlayer for sound that can be played number of times .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding is that `SoundPool` cannot be used for sounds longer than several seconds or audio files >1MB. Use `MediaPlayer` in those cases.

Either use this for each play of a sound:

```
MediaPlayer.create(YourActivity.this, R.raw.your_sound).start();
```

or create `MediaPlayer` object, play same sound as many times as needed, then `release()` the object.

Comment: Mediaplayer cant be used more than once without side effects, most time, previously mediaplayer's got ignored